# Array_push() not working in a for loop

Tags: php

```
$cust = rand(50,100);
$minutes = rand(200,2500);
$minutesarr = array();
function minutesTable()
{
        global $cust,$i,$minutes,$minutesarr;
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $cust; $i++)
        {
            array_push($minutesarr,$minutes);

        }          
}
```

I've even resorted to using `$minutesarr[$i] = $minutes;` but that didn't work either which is strangely mysterious.

Edit: Whoops I forgot to add the $cust variable in the thread. Let me add that in there to prevent confusion.

Comment: What's the value of `$cust` when this is run? Is the loop even executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the following must be happening:

1. The function is never run
2. `$cust` is never declared
3. `$cust` is less than 1

So confirm/fix the above and you should be dandy.

Also I should note that you probably intended the `$minutes` variable to contain a different number for every loop, but it won't with your current code. You have to run the `rand` function again for every loop to get a new number.

---

**To answer your comment**

Expanding upon your current code:

```
$cust = rand(50,100);
$minutesarr = array();
function minutesTable()
{
        global $cust, $minutesarr;

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $cust; $i++)
        {
            $minutes = rand(200,2500);
            array_push($minutesarr, $minutes);
        }
}

// RUN the function :-P
minutesTable();
```

Comment: +1, just compute $minutes each time you run the loop to have different values at every call.

Comment: *facepalm* of course...I forgot to run the function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As the `$cust` value is not declared, your loop isn't even starting...

declare

```
$cust = some number
```

before starting the loop

Next time, if you want to check if a loop is running, just put a log message (or whatsoever the programming language allows you to do for debugging) inside of it, run the code then check whether it has been called or not.

Comment: Yeah I just forgot to put $cust into the example code. My bad. I had it original in my code.

Comment: oh I see you've updated the code. So, now, the only reason why the loop should not start is that you're not running the minutesTable() function (as mentioned by Codemonkey).